# Create Upload Session in Sharepoint

Tags: node.js, sharepoint

I am trying to upload a large file of 50mb to sharepoint and I am getting an error. I want upload the file in chunks and I want to create an upload session with the url  `${siteUrl}/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Folder/path')/Files/add(url='${fileName}', overwrite=true)/startupload`. So I am getting this error `{"code":"-2147024809, System.ArgumentException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"parameters.Content, parameters.ContentStream\\r\\nParameter name: Specified value is not supported for the parameters.Content, parameters.ContentStream parameter."},`. How can I be able to create an upload session so that I can get the upload id and use it to upload in chunks?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0), it also provides endpoints for [uploading large file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) by creating UploadSession and then uploading them in chunks. Hope this helps. Best Wishes.

[image]